# using sql concat() in django for concatenating two columns

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

Let's say I have a table xyz in MySQL which has three columns: col1, col2 and col3 (all varchar). I am using python with Django for my server which uses this model. Now I want to write an expression in Django ORM which should result in this query in MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE col3 != CONCAT(col1, col2)
```

I know Django `filter`/`exclude`, but than filters based on fixed values, not columns:

```
xyz.objects.exclude(col3='something')
```

or

```
xyz.objects.filter(col3='something')
```

(PS: I know it's a bad table design if one column contains redundant information from other columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use some SQL for this. Either `raw`:

```
xyz.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE col3 != CONCAT(col1, col2)")
```

or `extra`:

```
xyz.objects.extra(where=["col3 != CONCAT(col1, col2)"])
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Both of those return Django models.

Answer (score 4):

In `Django>=1.8` this is also possible:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Concat
queryset = xyz.objects.exclude(col3=Concat('col1', 'col2'))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I moved out that project and company long ago... :)